# Is the solution to a Fokker-Planck equation always non-negative, under any conditions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

On a domain $(0;T) \times (0;L)$, I have the equation

$$0 = \partial_t f - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\cdot \partial_{xx}^2 f + \partial_x(p \cdot f),$$

where $p$ is fixed real function on the domain. I also have the boundary conditions $f(t,0) = 0$ and $f(0,x) = F(x)$, which is a known non-negative function.

Can I, under any conditions (which do not force $p$ to be zero everywhere), guarantee that any solution $f$ to this equation is non-negative or at least bounded below by a certain negative constant?

Comment: How about weak maximum principle for parabolic equations?

Comment: is $p$ depending on x?

Comment: Yes, $p$ is depending on x. :( Do you have a good reference, @tchao?

Comment: Evans "Partial Differential Equations", Chapter 7.1. This is a very basic (but very good!) book and it gives references to more special literature. You can find it, for example, here: https://books.google.de/books/about/Partial_Differential_Equations.html?id=5Pv4LVB_m8AC&redir_esc=y. Google also shows some .pdf files.